# Problema con mi componente con el metodo map y HUD useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

soy nuevo en lo que respecta a react y tuve un problema con un componente que llame lista y hasta hace un dia funcionaba pero lo volvi a iniciar y salio un error en el array creado al final siendo que no es asi estoy seguro que esta dentro pero no termino de entender, si he seguido lo que salia de un curso que estoy haciendo que es el segundo video y es nuevo por lo que no deberia haber cambiado tanto la sintaxis desde ese tiempo a ahora ademas de que funcioanaba antes pero no termino de entender los llaves estan bien cerradas use el map con un array creado dentro de useState.

He aqui el componente aclaro que para poder verlo ya deben tener react antes:

```
import React,{useState, Fragment} from 'react';


const Lista = () => {

    const [arrayNumero, setNumero] = useState([1,2,3,4,5]);

    const addElement = () =>{
        console.log("click")
    }



    return(
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Lista</h2>
            <button onClick={addElement}>Agregar</button>
            {

                arrayNumero.map((item, index) => {  
                    return <p key={index}>{item} - {index}</p>
                })
            }
        </Fragment>
        );


export default Lista;
```

Estoy siguiendo un curso de react nuevo y este seria el segundo video del mismo pero no termino de entender porque no funciona mi código si segui la guía.

Desde ya muchas gracis

Comment: Parece un error de sintáxis aqui: `(item, index) => { return <p key={index}>{item} - {index}</p>)}`, primero deberías cerrar el corchete y al final el paréntesis, asi:  `(item, index) => { return <p key={index}>{item} - {index}</p>})`

Comment: Hola si ya lo arregle lo que paso fue que lo volvi a como estaba antes pero a un me tira error de sintaxis ya no se que puede ser igual gracias por tu aport

Comment: Cual es el restultado que esperas al presionar click?

Comment: Por ahora que me avise en consola que funciona pero lo inició con la terminal y me sale sintaxis de error en el export ya la verdad no se porque ahora